# visualizing training images from training data batch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

**Visualizing  training images from the training data batch**
train_images, train_labels = next(train_data.as_numpy_iterator())
show_25_images(train_images, train_labels)

typeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 #Visualize training images from the training data batch
----> 2 train_images, train_labels = next(train_data.as_numpy_iterator())
3 show_25_images(train_images, train_labels)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in as_numpy_iterator(self)
614           component_spec,
615           (tensor_spec.TensorSpec, ragged_tensor.RaggedTensorSpec)):
--> 616         raise TypeError(
617             f"`tf.data.Dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` is not supported for "
618             f"datasets that produce values of type {component_spec.value_type}")

TypeError: `tf.data.Dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` is not supported for datasets that produce values of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.util.structure.NoneTensor'>

set of images

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the dataset to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` or  `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors()` to create a `tf.data.Dataset`.

**For example:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

(train_images, train_labels),(test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images=train_images/255
test_images=test_images/255

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
```

Then you can iterate `tf.data.dataset` through `as_numpy_iterator()`

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
train_images, train_labels = next(train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
```

or

```
for train_images, train_labels in train_dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    print(train_images, train_labels)
```